# Windows Text Editor With SCP Support and No Install

Tags: windows-7, windows, text-editing

Is there a programmer's text editor (line numbers, syntax highlighting) for Windows 7 that offers

1. Edit in Place via SCP
2. A non-administrator instalation/runs without instalation

Free is nice, commercial with demo is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Komodo Edit](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit) will do this I think. ([Komodo Edit Portable](https://web.archive.org/web/20170613124931/https://sourceforge.net/projects/askomodoeditpaf/)).

It's free and has a very nice feature set.

Comment: Perfect.  I'll never understand why developers opt for the installer route if it's possible to create a stand alone version.

Comment: I agree.  There should at least be an option in the installer: "install as stand alone?"

Answer (score 2):

[vim](http://www.vim.org/) is another option:

uses `pscp` (from [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)) to do the 'edit over scp' part, read more:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_PuTTY_pscp_with_Vim

Answer (score 0):

I found PsPad

http://www.pspad.com/en/download.php

that has a "portable" (no installer) version